# why refleaction of light on floor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I have a area lamp pointing front side with emission of 100 in cycles. Why the shadow or glow on the floor. As show in the image below. I want to have a a glow as seen below but there should be no glow on the floor. Any way for the solution.

[image]

Comment: maybe put the floor on another layer and manage this in the Compositor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area light is **NOT** parallel.

[image]

The floor is lit by the indirect light. Also the reflection.

[image]

Use emission material instead of area light if you like the result in the picture.

[image]

Comment: so the solution plz

Comment: Check the last part of the answer:)